# Does inbound=outbound apply to GPL-family without a CLA?

Tags: gpl, lgpl, agpl-3.0, collaboration, contributor-agreements

The traditional expectation for contributions to a free software project are **"inbound=outbound"** [[1](https://opensource.com/law/11/7/trouble-harmony-part-1#contribution-policies-and-free-software-tradition)] [[2](http://producingoss.com/en/contributor-agreements.html)]. That is, if the project is under license X, contributions are made under license X.

Does this apply to a project released under any/all of the following licenses with no additional CLA?

- LGPL v2-only
- GPL v2-only
- LGPL v2-or-later
- GPL v2-or-later
- LGPL v3-only
- GPL v3-only
- AGPL v3-only
- LGPL v3-or-later
- GPL v3-or-later
- AGPL v3-or-later

I am not concerned with compatibility beyond that, just that in each case that contributions are "by default" the same GPL-variant as the original project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, submissions to a GPL codebase remain under the same GPL variant. This is specifically because of the copyleft mechanism. For example, [from section 10 of the GPLv3 license text](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html#section10):

> Each time you convey a covered work, the recipient automatically receives a license from the original licensors, to run, modify and propagate that work, subject to this License.

This applies to all listed variants of the GPL (version 2/3, only/or-later clause, A/L/GPL variant). Specific modifications to the license terms are sometimes allowed (for example, by the "or later" clause), but "by default" the terms remain the same.